# heroku /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby.exe\r’: No such file or directory problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have been deploying my app to the same heroku server for the past few weeks and it has been working great.

I just tried to deploy my latest code and got this error when trying to run:

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

The error I got was this:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby.exe\r’: No such file or directory problem
```

I have looked at many other threads concerning this problem and taken their advice.

The most common answer was to change the first line of the bin/bundle, bin/rails and bin/rake folders from this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
```

To this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

However did this not work for me and I keep getting the same error

Any other possible solutions to this problem?

I am running on a windows machine

Comment: I believe the command is `heroku run rake db:migrate`. So `rake`, not `rails`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: In newer versions of rails you can use either or.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue here, running Rails 5 . Though I am not 100% sure, I believe it happened because of a problem with the line endings on the bin/ files.

I altered the global seeting on Git, dealing with line endings:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

And then updated the bin files, with:

```
rails app:update:bin
```

(on previous rails versions it goes by `rake rails:update:bin`)

More on how Git deals with this issue (and how to refresh a repository, if necessary) here: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/